# TypeError: 'cv2.face_EigenFaceRecognizer' object is not callable

Tags: opencv3.1

I ran into an error which i do not know where and what is causing it.
Please i need help.

```
def train(self,images,lables, recogType=0):
        self.images = images
        self.lables = np.array(lables)

        'arg = recogType:[cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create(),cv2.face.FisherFaceRecognizer_create(),cv2.face.EigenFaceRecognizer_create()'
        recogs = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create(),cv2.face.FisherFaceRecognizer_create(),cv2.face.EigenFaceRecognizer_create()
        self.recognizer = recogs[recogType]()    
        self.recognizer.train(self.images,self.lables)
```

Comment: I'd guess change `self.recognizer = recogs[recogType]()` to `self.recognizer = recogs[recogType]`

Comment: @doctorlove i appreciate your quick reply to help, after changing self.recognizer = recogs[recogType]() to self.recognizer=recogs[recogType], this is the new error thrown:  error: (-5:Bad argument) Empty training data was given. You'll need more than one sample to learn a model. in function 'train'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specific problem is with this line:

```
self.recognizer = recogs[recogType]()
```

By placing braces `()` on the end, you are trying to call the recognizer, as the error says. Change this to

```
self.recognizer = recogs[recogType]
```

//Disclaimer - there may be other problems.